In Visual Studio C#, can I change the debug value being displayed when I hover over a variable of a system type?
When inspecting a nullable bool (bool?), I currently see the value of the "HasValue" field. Since this is also a boolean, it's super confusing.
Is there a way to override this?
Here it looks like the value is 'true'

While we clearly see it's 'false' if we expand the object. The ToString most likely assumed the value of HasValue. It seems VS has no built-in way to recognise nullables and just picks the alphabetically first one?


Well, you see I'd much rather see the actual "false" value in the summary. In the top screenshot it is very easy to mistake this value actually holding the value "true". imo it's objectively a bug in Visual Studio.

I'm not seeing the same behavior (v2). You've tagged this VS 2019. Is there a reason you're not using VS 2022?

You should be able to 'pin' the Value property so that it shows up first when inspecting. In Visual Studio 2022 it handles nullable boolean values differently and simply displays it as if it was a regular bool when inspecting.

@gunr2171 I think the more interesting scenario is bool? taskList = false, but even then VS2022 will display the actual value instead of the HasValue-flag.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain, whoops, you're right. v3

After my test, whether it is VS2019 or VS2022, I did not see HasValue, and the default display was Value. Perhaps you should list the steps to reproduce this problem, or update to VS2022 as mentioned in the above comments.

I guess something is wrong with my install or configuration, or maybe the Unity toolkit is interfering. Using the pin feature, I still see the same 'true' value. This is how I call it. I'm not doing anything particularly special afaik. I will cope with it until I find a need to upgrade to VS2022. Thanks for the input.

In Visual Studio 2022 it just works, I can't even see the innards in the details.
